Stuck deploying application on GCP
First of all, I want to say I'm a beginner in this stuff. I'm trying to deploy a simple application, with nodejs, a mysql server, and an nginx reverse proxy to balance workloads to my nodejs replicas. I'm doing all this with Cloud Run.
I pushed my images do GCR, and tried to deploy them on Cloud Run, but it keeps saying that the container failed to listen on PORT=8080, even though I passed it in the Dockerfile.
That's the Error:

Revision 'app1-00003-bcm' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable within the allocated timeout. This can happen when the container port is misconfigured or if the timeout is too short. The health check timeout can be extended. Logs for this revision might contain more information. Logs URL: Abrir o Cloud Logging  For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start

I tried to deploy my working Docker-compose setup on GCP's Cloud Run and it keeps saying that the application couldn't listen in the expected port:8080 even though it's explicit both in the code and Dockefile.

Your post does not provide details to help you. The reported error probably means that you coded the startup scripts incorrectly. Tip 1: Cloud Run is stateless, why are you trying to deploy a database that requires persistent storage? Tip 2: Develop on your local desktop and test the container in Docker before trying to deploy in the cloud. Tip 3: Cloud Run already includes a proxy to load balance. Tip 4: nodejs replicas - What is that with respect to Cloud Run?

I recommend starting with something very simple so that you understand serverless, containerization, and Cloud Run.
